# Reallocating memory for an array?

Tags: c++

```
void IntVector::expand(){ 
    int cap2 = cap * 2; 
    int* data2 = new int[cap2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data2[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = data2;
    cap = cap2; 
}
```

Expand doubles the capacity of vector and is to reallocate memory for the dynamically allocated array and update the value of capacity.

However, I am having continuous problems with this function as my class's test harness continues to crash on me and states that there was undefined behavior.

Edit:

```
void IntVector::expand(){
    if(cap == 0 || sz == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    int cap2 = cap * 2; 
    int* data2 = new int[cap2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data2[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = data2;
    cap = cap2; 
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount){
    if(cap == 0 || sz == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    cap += amount;
    int *data2 = new int[cap];
    //copy(data, data+sz, data2);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data2[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = data2;

}
```

I am still having many problems with these two functions.  The class's test harness keeps crashing and reporting undefined behavior.  Should I just post the rest of my code?

Edit 2:

```
void IntVector::expand(){
    if(cap == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    int cap2 = cap * 2; 
    int* data2 = new int[cap2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data2[i] = data[i];
    }
    if(data != NULL){
        delete[] data;
    }
    data = data2;
    cap = cap2; 
}
```

Edit:

Header

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H
#define INTVECTOR_H

using namespace std;
class IntVector{
private:
    unsigned sz;
    unsigned cap;
    int *data;
public:
    IntVector();
    IntVector(unsigned size);
    IntVector(unsigned size, int value);
    unsigned size() const;
    unsigned capacity() const;
    bool empty() const;
    const int & at (unsigned index) const;
    const int & front() const;
    const int & back() const;
    ~IntVector();
    void insert(unsigned index, int value);
    void erase(unsigned index);
    void push_back(int value);
    void pop_back();
    void clear();
    void resize(unsigned size);
    void resize(unsigned size, int value);
    void reserve(unsigned n);
    void assign(unsigned n, int value);
    int & at(unsigned index);
    int & front();
    int & back();
private:
    void expand();
    void expand(unsigned amount);
};

#endif
```

Body

```
#include "IntVector.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;



IntVector::IntVector(){
    sz = 0;
    cap = 0;
    data = NULL;
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size){
    if(size = 0){
        cap = 1;
        size = 1;
        data = new int[sz];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
    }
}

IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size, int value){
    if(size = 0){
        cap = 1;
        size = 1;
        data = new int[sz];
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data[i] = value;
    }
}

unsigned IntVector::size() const{
    return sz;
}

unsigned IntVector::capacity() const{
    return cap;
}

bool IntVector::empty() const{
    if(sz > 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

const int &IntVector::at(unsigned index) const{
    if(index > sz){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        return data[index];
    }
}

const int &IntVector::front() const{
    return data[0];
}

const int &IntVector::back() const{
    return data[sz - 1];
}

IntVector::~IntVector(){
    delete[] data;
}

void IntVector::expand(){
    if(cap == 0){
        cap = 1;
    }
    cap = cap * 2;
    int* data_copy = new int[cap];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data_copy[i] = data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = data_copy;
}

void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount){
    if(cap == 0){
        cap = 1;
    }
    cap += amount;
    int *data_copy = new int[cap];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        data_copy[i] = data[i];
    }
    //copy(data, data + sz, data_copy);
    delete[] data;
    data = data_copy;

}



void IntVector::insert(unsigned index, int value){
    if(index > sz || cap == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        sz += 1;
        if(sz = cap){
            expand();
        }

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= sz; i++){
            if(i = index){
                data[i] = value;
            }
            if(i > index){
                data[i - 1] = data[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

void IntVector::erase(unsigned index){
    if(index > sz || cap == 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= sz; i++){
            if(i = index){
                data[i] = data[i + 1];
            }
        }
        sz -= 1;
    }
}

void IntVector::push_back(int value){
    sz += 1;
    if(sz > cap){
        expand();
    }
    data[sz] = value;
}

void IntVector::pop_back(){
    if(sz < 0 || cap <= 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    sz -= 1;
}

void IntVector::clear(){
    sz = 0;
}

void IntVector::resize(unsigned size, int value){
    if(size < sz){
        sz = size;
    }
    else if(size > sz){
        int a = size - sz;
        for (unsigned int i = a; i < size; i++){
            data[i] = value;
        }
    }
    if(sz > cap){
        int b = cap * 2;
        int c = sz - cap;
        if(b > c){
            expand();
        }
        else{
            expand(c);
        }
    }
}

void IntVector::reserve(unsigned n){
    int a = cap * 2;
    int b = n - cap;
    if(a > b){
        expand(a);
    }
    else{
        expand(b);
    }
}

void IntVector::assign(unsigned n, int value){
    sz = n;
    if(sz > cap){
        int a = cap * 2;
        int b = n - cap;
        if(a > b){
            expand(a);
        }
        else{
            expand(b);
        }
    }
    data = new int[sz];
    *data = value;
}

int & IntVector::at(unsigned index){
    if(index >= sz){
        exit(1);
    }
    return data[index];
}

int & IntVector::front(){
    return data[0];
}

int & IntVector::back(){
    return data[sz - 1];
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: I made the suggested adjustments to the code but am still having many problems with the class's test harness.

Comment: Every line that reads `*data = *data2` ought to read `data = data2`. Putting the asterisk in front dereferences the pointer; this is not what you want to do.

Comment: @Patrick87 I assigned them to data = data2 but am sitll running into many problems.

Comment: What errors do you get with the fixed code? Suggest updating the post to reflect the code you're currently experiencing errors with.

Comment: It's those two functions and their entirety.  They just aren't working properly right now and I just don't know why.

Comment: When I remove delete[] data and have delete data; instead, the harness goes through but gives the error that delete was called on an array allocated with new[].

Comment: If you're using the default constructor, then you're probably hitting a bug where `delete[]` vomits on a `NULL` pointer. Either check for `NULL` or initialize your pointer to something non-`NULL`. Edited my answer.

Comment: @user3314899 - Why don't you post this "test harness"?  There are things that were pointed out to you in your other thread that you did *not* address, namely implementing a copy constructor and assignment operator.  That test harness you speak of can easily break the class you've written with no more than 2 lines of code (I also showed this to you already in the other thread you started).

Comment: In addition, no one is going to want to flip back-and-forth trying to cobble together missing pieces of your code.  Where is the destructor in your example in *this* thread?

Comment: That is a lot of code for a question. Can you narrow the problem down a little

Comment: @EdHeal when assigning size and cap in my first three IntVector functions, should I add an extra 1 to compensate for the null in the array?

Comment: @user3314899 - Not really thought about it as it is too much code for a question on this forum. But I would suggest that doubling in expand is the wrong way to grow - exponential growth. Would put a cap there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you practically have duplicate expand() functions.  You should just call the 1 argument expand function from the one that doesn't provide an argument.

```
void IntVector::expand() 
{
    expand(cap * 2);
}
```

Now you work on the expand( ) function that takes one argument.

```
void IntVector::expand(unsigned amount)
{
   if (cap == 0 || sz == 0 || amount == 0)
     return;
   cap += amount;
   int *data2 = new int[cap];
   std::copy(data, data + sz, data2);
   delete[] data;
   data = data2;
```

}

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this code (note that I just returned, and not call exit(1)).  Also a check for amount is done to make sure you actually need to change the capacity.

So you need to post your test harness, and the rest of your class.  We have no idea how you're using this class.

Now to this:

```
IntVector::IntVector(unsigned size)
{
    sz = size;
    cap = size;
    data = new int[sz];
    *data = 0;   // what if size is 0?
}
```

That code fails if the size passed is 0.  Yes, you can technically allocate an array of size 0, but you cannot dereference that memory, as you did in that line.  You should be checking if size if 0.

Comment: The homework for that function says "Sets both the size and capacity of the IntVector to the value of the parameter passed in and dynamically allocates an array of that size as well. (Don't forget to initialize all values in your array to 0.)"

Edit: Uploaded my full header and body.

Answer (score 0):

(From comments)

Every line that reads `*data = *data2` ought to read `data = data2`. Putting the asterisk in front dereferences the pointer; this is not what you want to do.

(Response to edited question)

The default constructor sets `data = NULL`. When you try to delete this pointer, you will get an error. You should always check `if (data != NULL)` before `delete[] data`.

(Also, the other constructor has `*data = 0`. This probably isn't right. If you want to zero the whole thing out, you can use `memset` or `ZeroMemory`... or a `for` loop like in your other functions.)

Comment: Edited my original question with the revised code.  It is still giving me problems with the test harness as it keeps saying that there is undefined behavior.